# Discrete Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG)

Tags: derivatives, convolution, laplacian, image-processing

In Image processing, one often uses the discrete Laplacian of Gaussian (LoG) to do edge detection with

$LoG(x,y) = -\frac{1}{\pi \sigma^4}[1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}]\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Various sources [here](http://academic.mu.edu/phys/matthysd/web226/Lab02.htm), [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gradient/node8.html) or [here](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm) give discrete Kernels of the LoG to be convoluted with the input image to yield the filtered version. However, I do not understand the derivation of this Kernel from the function.

One possible Kernel for $\sigma = 1.4$ is

$K = \begin{bmatrix}0.0& 1.0& 1.0& 2.0&   2.0&   2.0&   1.0& 1.0& 0.0\\
           1.0& 2.0& 4.0& 5.0&   5.0&   5.0&   4.0& 2.0& 1.0\\
           1.0& 4.0& 5.0& 3.0&   0.0&   3.0&   5.0& 4.0& 1.0\\
           2.0& 5.0& 3.0& -12.0& -24.0& -12.0& 3.0& 5.0& 2.0\\
           2.0& 5.0& 0.0& -24.0& -40.0& -24.0& 0.0& 5.0& 2.0\\
           2.0& 5.0& 3.0& -12.0& -24.0& -12.0& 3.0& 5.0& 2.0\\
           1.0& 4.0& 5.0& 3.0&   0.0&   3.0&   5.0& 4.0& 1.0\\
           1.0& 2.0& 4.0& 5.0&   5.0&   5.0&   4.0& 2.0& 1.0\\
           0.0& 1.0& 1.0& 2.0&   2.0&   2.0&   1.0& 1.0& 0.0\end{bmatrix}$

My question is, how these discrete Kernels are derived from the $LoG(x,y)$ function. Is there any scaling factor involved? Is it an integration over the discrete pixel area?

My calculated values for the central point (-40.0) are:

$LoG(0,0) \approx -0.1624$

and

$\iint\limits_{-0.5}^{0.5}{LoG(x,y)} dx dy \approx -0.0761$

Comment: I find $LoG(0,0)\approx=-0.0828587$, with e.g. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F%28pi*sigma%5E4%29*%281-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2F%282*sigma%5E2%29%29*exp%28-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2F%282*sigma%5E2%29%29+where+sigma%3D1.4+x%3D0+y%3D0), why?

Comment: I'll update my answer with the code and the exact result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is scaling. The matrix $K$ is simply a $n\times n$ matrix with $n$ being odd and

$K(i,j)=LoG(i-\frac{n-1}{2},j-\frac{n-1}{2})$.

The whole matrix can be scaled for easier calculation in the integer range.

The following python code produces a matrix, that is "close enough" to the wanted output:

```
import numpy as np

def LoG(sigma, x, y):
    laplace = -1/(np.pi*sigma**4)*(1-(x**2+y**2)/(2*sigma**2))*np.exp(-(x**2+y**2)/(2*sigma**2))
    return laplace

def LoG_discrete(sigma, n):
    l = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            l[i,j] = LoG(sigma, (i-(n-1)/2),(j-(n-1)/2))
    return l

sigma = 1.4

l = np.round(LoG_discrete(sigma, 9)*(-40/LoG(sigma,0,0)))
```

$K = \begin{bmatrix}0& 0& 1& 2& 2& 2& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 3& 5& 5& 5& 3& 1& 0\\
1& 3& 5& 3& 0& 3& 5& 3& 1\\
2& 5& 3&-12& -23& -12& 3& 5& 2\\
2& 5& 0& -23& -40& -23& 0& 5& 2\\
2& 5& 3&-12& -23& -12& 3& 5& 2\\
1& 3& 5& 3& 0& 3& 5& 3& 1\\
0& 1& 3& 5& 5& 5& 3& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 2& 2& 2& 1& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about scaling, that is, how to go from the $LoG$ formula to the matrix $K$ shown in your question? I try to calculate this exact same $K$ with Python, but with no luck.

Comment: There are several formulas, that produce slightly different results taking e.g. different sub-pixel positions for the aproximation. One other possible implementation (in Java) is linked here: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/logdemo.htm

Comment: I think the important sentence is in http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gradient/node8.html : "The kernel of any other sizes can be obtained by approximating the continuous expression of LoG given above. However, make sure that the sum (or average) of all elements of the kernel has to be zero (similar to the Laplace kernel) so that the convolution result of a homogeneous regions is always zero."